# how to launch a command window from Python

Tags: python, windows, console, subprocess, popen

I'd like to use Python 2.6 on Windows to launch several **separate** command windows, each running their own Python script.  The purpose is: these are clients, and I'm trying to load up the server with requests from multiple quasi-independent clients.

I don't need to communicate with the client during or after the run, but I do need to send each a different commmandline arg, and I'd like each client's output to scroll in its own "console".

From the DOS command line, the "start" command does what I'd like.  I can either:

```
start perf_test.py 2
```

or

```
start cmd /c perf_test.py 3
```

or

```
start cmd /c python perf_test.py 4
```

(These will work for you if you have your "file associations" setup correctly for *.py files.  There are other threads on that, if you need help.  Or, use full paths to the python exe and/or your script.)

My challenge is: How do I get the same effect from Python?

Using `subprocess` library, I've tried variations like this:

```
from subprocess import *
p = Popen(["perf_test.py", "4"], shell=True, stdin=PIPE)
```

But even with `shell=True`, the output is commingled in the window I'm already running in.  Adding `stdout=PIPE` stops that, but then I have to read `p.stdout` or use `p.communicate()`.  Adding "cmd" to the Popen gets approximately the same:

```
p = Popen(["cmd", "/c", "perf_test.py", "4"], shell=True, stdin=PIPE)
```

None of the above achieve the effect I'm looking for, which is: "**pop open a new, distinct window for this script, and watch its output scroll by in its own console**" (because I really want to run N of these clients in parallel).

One other thing I turned to *almost* works, too.

```
import os
os.startfile("perf_test.py")
```

This returns immediately, and an actual dosbox pops up. Yay! Success! That is, until I try to add an argument.  This fails:

```
os.startfile("perf_test.py 5")
```

with error "The system cannot find the file specified"... because it is adding "[SPACE]5" to the filename.  (The purpose of the argument is that each "perf_test" needs to have an assigned ID, so that they hit the server as different instances.)

Other approaches I've considered, and really don't like for various reasons:

- Run each "perf_test" in its own thread.  (But I really want to see the output each in its own console.)
- Make my own pseudo-consoles with Tk. (Figure I'll just hit different threading problems there.)
- Dynamically write a .BAT file on the fly with the lines "start perf_test.py 1", "start perf_test.py 2", etc., then launch that .BAT file with `Popen` or `startfile`.

I expect the last will work... and I guess is my last resort, if I can't get a Python script to do it directly.

Thanks for any input / insights!

Comment: Do you want each console to stay open after the Python script finishes execution?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use:

```
import os
os.system("start python perf_test.py 5")
```

Answer (score 1):

Well I had the same problem. It was solved with this method.
You should Try:

```
import os
os.system('chrome.exe') # open Chrome (.exe  file)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Code :**

```
user = raw_input("welcome to cmd: ")
def print_perms(chars, minlen, maxlen): 
    for n in range(minlen, maxlen+1): 
        for perm in itertools.product(chars, repeat=n): 
            print(''.join(perm))
```

Comment: Why should OP use your code? Please give a more detailed answer

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
os.system("start cmd")
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you might want would be

```
import os
os.system('cmd /k "[your command here]"')
```

I'm not sure if you would like it that way, but I just want to help.